# Kotlin syntax for LiveData observer?

Tags: android, kotlin

I have the following bit of code in my `HomeActivity` to use `LiveData`.

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

    // Show the launch splash screen.
    //
    this.setContentView(R.layout.activity_home)

    this.viewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(HomeViewModel::class.java)

    this.viewModel.getUser().observe(this, Observer { user: User? ->

    });

}
```

While this seems to work, what does the following part mean?

```
Observer { user: User? ->

}
```

This must result in an object that conforms to the `Observer` interface which has

```
void onChanged (T t)
```

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/arch/lifecycle/Observer.html

How does

```
Observer { user: User? ->

}
```

result in an object with an `onChanged` method?

I don't know what  putting the name of an interface in front of a lambda expression means.

Thanks!

Comment: As this is all I could find online - can anyone tell me if observing functions, like in the question `this.viewModel.getUser().observe(this, Observer { user: User? ->` is a used syntax anymore? Or is it just liveData that should be used now, e.g. `viewModel.user.observe`

Answer (score 24, accepted):

This is called **SAM Conversion**, a concept that helps interacting with Java *Single Abstract Method* Interfaces like in your example.

The following creates an implementation of `Runnable`, where the single abstract method is `run()`:

```
val runnable = Runnable { println("This runs in a runnable") }
```

It’s described in the docs: https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/java-interop.html#sam-conversions

Alternatively, but more verbose, would be to use an `object`:

```
val runnable2 = object : Runnable {
        override fun run() {
            println("This runs in a runnable")
        }
}
```

Both are examples of anonymous implementations of that `interface`. It's of course also possible to create a concrete subclass and instantiate it then.

```
class MyRunnable : Runnable {
    override fun run() {
        println("This runs in a runnable")
    }
}

val runnable3 = MyRunnable()
```

Comment: Thank you, s1m0nw1. What would the more verbose way of writing it that explicitly defines the onChanged method?

Comment: When you implement the interface the normal way wie class MyObserver : Observer {//method impl}

Comment: It seems it can be written as 

    `this.viewModel.getUser().observe(this, object: Observer<User> {
        override fun onChanged(user: User?) {
    
        }
    });`

Comment: This is also possible. I've added the alternatives

Comment: @s1m0nw1 There is one thing surprising me here. I tried removing the `Observer` before the lambda but it doesn't work. Why? In SAM conversion we must be able not to use the interface name and just provide the lambda body.

Answer (score 11):

in Kotlin the `Observer { }` lambda gives you param `it`, you can rename it as you want and use. by default data will be available with `it.something()` etc...

JAVA:

```java
... new Observer {
  void onChanged(User user){
     user.something()
  }
}
```

KOTLIN

```kotlin
... object : Observer<User> {
   fun onChanged(user: User){
        user.something()
   }
}
```

OR

```kotlin
... Observer {
   it.something()
}
```

you can rename it to whatever you want like

```kotlin
... Observer { myUser ->
   myUser.something()
}
```

Answer (score 2):

To omit the `Observer { ... }` part just add `import androidx.lifecycle.observe` and use it like this:

```
this.viewModel.user.observe(this) { user: User? ->
    // ...
}
```