# Lambda implementation of interface in kotlin

Tags: java, methods, lambda, interface, kotlin

What would be the equivalent of that code in kotlin, nothing seems to work of what I try:

```
public interface AnInterface {
    void doSmth(MyClass inst, int num);
}
```

init:

```
AnInterface impl = (inst, num) -> {
    //...
}
```

Comment: For future readers, you may also want to look at https://stackoverflow.com/a/58725404/48136

Answer (score 39, accepted):

If `AnInterface` is Java, it can work with [SAM conversion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47605970/8073652):

```
val impl = AnInterface { inst, num -> 
     //...
}
```

Otherwise, if the interface is Kotlin:

- Since Kotlin 1.4, it's possible to write [**functional interfaces**](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/fun-interfaces.html#sam-conversions) :

  ```kotlin
  fun interface AnInterface {
       fun doSmth(inst: MyClass, num: Int)
  }
  val impl = AnInterface { inst, num -> ... }
  ```
- Otherwise, if the interface is not functional

  ```kotlin
  interface AnInterface {
       fun doSmth(inst: MyClass, num: Int)
  }
  ```

  you can use the `object` syntax for implementing it anonymously:

  ```kotlin
  val impl = object : AnInterface {
      override fun doSmth(inst:, num: Int) {
          //...
      }
  }
  ```

Comment: Why Kotlin interfaces doesn't have a similar SAM conversion to that of Java? Any way can this AnInterface { inst, num -> } apply to Kotlin interface as well?

Comment: well you can upvote this issue here:
https://discuss.kotlinlang.org/t/sam-conversion-on-kotlin-interfaces/1433

Comment: What if I wanted to pass it to a function that takes AnInterface as a parameter. Do I write this?  myFun(object : AnInterface { override fun doSmth(ints:, num: Int) { ... } }) There has to be a better way!

Answer (score 22):

If you're rewriting both the interface and its implementations to Kotlin, then you should just delete the interface and use a functional type:

```
val impl: (MyClass, Int) -> Unit = { inst, num -> ... }
```

Comment: This is the true answer... the other 2 does not address the lambda implementation. However if I still want to use my own declared interface (for readability reason), does it mean I cannot use lambda?

Comment: @SiraLam you can declare a default variable name for a functional type: `val listener: (name: Class, other: OtherClass) -> Unit`

Comment: @SiraLam If you want the interface for readability reasons then you're probably suffering from Primitive Obsession. tl;dr - don't use primitives as arguments. What does a function with this signature do? `(String) -> String` Without a name, you can't reason about it. Now, what does a function with this signature do? `(UserId) -> PhoneNumber` - Well, the only reasonable implementation would be something that looks up user data by ID, then pulls out the phone number and returns it. If your functions don't take primitives then you don't usually need to wrap them in an interface for readability.

Answer (score 4):

You can use an [object expression](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/object-declarations.html)

So it would look something like this:

```
val impl = object : AnInterface {
    override fun(doSmth: Any, num: Int) {
        TODO()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you can also do something like this, using `@lambda` label

```
interface AnInterface {
     fun doSmth(inst: MyClass, num: Int)
}

val impl = AnInterface lambda@{inst, num ->
    //..
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To anyone who is reading this in 2022, Kotlin now has Functional (SAM) Interfaces. Please see https://kotlinlang.org/docs/fun-interfaces.html

Maybe it will save others some time depending on your use case.

Comment: Thank you, this should be the selected answer