# Type mismatch error on custom interface call

Tags: android, kotlin, interface, android-recyclerview

I'm redesigning an app I've been working on with Kotlin for the purpose of getting used to the language.  In my RecyclerView adapter, I have created a custom `OnLongClickListener` interface for long clicks:

```
interface OnItemLongClickListener{
    fun onItemLongClick(entry: Entry)
}

fun setOnItemLongClickListener(listener: OnItemLongClickListener){
    this.listener = listener
}
```

And in the `onCreate()` of my `MainActivity.kt`, I am calling `setOnItemLongClickListener` on my adapter object to pass some intent extras:

```
    adapter!!.setOnItemLongClickListener { entry ->
        val intent = Intent(this@MainActivity, AddEditEntryActivity::class.java)

        intent.putExtra(AddEditEntryActivity.EXTRA_ID, entry.id)
        intent.putExtra(AddEditEntryActivity.EXTRA_USERNAME, entry.username)
        intent.putExtra(AddEditEntryActivity.EXTRA_HINT, entry.hint)
        intent.putExtra(AddEditEntryActivity.EXTRA_PASSWORD, entry.password)
        startActivityForResult(intent, EDIT_ENTRY_REQUEST)
    }
```

But the whole thing has a red underline and throws a `Type Mismatch` error.

I can supply more code per request.  I'm just keeping it short for now to avoid unnecessary clutter.

[image: Error]

Comment: it already has it's own `OnItemLongClickListener`. Rename your class to for example `MyItemLongClickListener`, and the method of setting it also not to confuse the compiler

Comment: @VladyslavMatviienko Made no difference.

Comment: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-7770

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should always include the complete error message, please. Without it, I can only guess that the issue is related to you supplying a lambda while an object of `OnItemLongClickListener` is being expected. You can change the code like this:

```
adapter!!.setOnItemLongClickListener (object: OnItemLongClickListener {
    override fun onItemLongClick(entry: Entry){
        //code goes here
    }
})
```

What you were trying to do only works for Java interfaces and is called [SAM conversion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48285220/8073652).

Comment: Sure.  I've added a screen of the error.  Check the edit :)

Comment: Yeah as I expected. My suggestion should help then

Comment: @Thank you.  I've accepted and upvoted your answer.  If you think that this was a well asked question, could you upvote me as well?