# How to implement a functional interface as lambda in Kotlin?

Tags: kotlin, lambda, functional-interface

I want to implement a functional kotlin interface (interface with a single abstract method) as a kotlin lambda. How to do that?

**Kotlin interface**

```
@FunctionalInterface
interface Foo{
  fun bar(input: String): String 
}
```

**Kotlin implementation** .

```
fun createFoo(): Foo {
   return { input: String -> "Hello $input!" }
}
```

↑ doesn't compile ↑

It has to be implemented as object, which is ugly as hell.

```
fun createFoo() = 
     object : Foo{
            override fun bar(input: String)= "Hello $input"
     }
```

---

EDIT: corrected my sample interface from java to kotlin

Comment: SAM conversion for Kotlin interfaces is not allowed [_by design_](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/java-interop.html#sam-conversions). Quoting the documentation: "note that this feature [SAM conversion] works only for Java interop; since Kotlin has proper function types, automatic conversion of functions into implementations of Kotlin interfaces is unnecessary and therefore unsupported."

Comment: Here is a related issue regarding this: [KT-7770](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-7770)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### since Kotlin v1.4

SAM conversion will be supported with version 1.4, with a new type inference algorithm.

See:

- [What to Expect in Kotlin 1.4 and Beyond](https://blog.jetbrains.com/kotlin/2019/12/what-to-expect-in-kotlin-1-4-and-beyond/#language-features)
- [More powerful type inference algorithm](https://blog.jetbrains.com/kotlin/2020/03/kotlin-1-4-m1-released/#new-type-inference)

---

### before Kotlin v1.4

It works if the companion object implements the `invoke` function taking a lambda.

**Kotlin interface**

```
interface Foo{
  fun bar(input: String): String

   companion object { 
      inline operator fun invoke(crossinline function: (String) -> String) =
                object : Foo{
                    override fun bar(input: String) = function(input)
                } 
   } 
}
```

**Kotlin implementation**

```
fun createFoo()= Foo { input: String -> "Hello $input!" }
```

---

Functional/SAM  interfaces defined in kotlin can't be implemented as Kotlin lambdas by design, see [KT-7770](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-7770).

In Kotlin an functional / SAM interface is considered as an anti-pattern, a function type should be declared instead: `(String)->String`. The function type can be expressed as typealias to make it look and feel like an interface: `typealias Foo=(String)->String`.

Note: The typealias is not visible in Java code only in Kotlin!

Answer (score 5):

Just add the `fun` keyword to your interface declaration:

```
fun interface Foo {
    fun bar(input: String): String 
}
```

It is the notation of functional interfaces in Kotlin (instead of `@FunctionalInterface` annotation in Java).

Now you can implement it like this:

```
Foo { input: String -> "Hello $input!" }
```

See more: https://kotlinlang.org/docs/fun-interfaces.html

Answer (score 2):

> I want to implement a functional kotlin interface (interface with a single abstract method) as a kotlin lambda. How to do that?

Can't

> It has to be implemented as object, which is ugly as hell.

Indeed.

---

You have two options:

1.) use `typealias`

```
typealias Foo = (String) -> String

fun createFoo(): Foo = { "Hello $it!" }
```

2.) depending on your API, you can define an extension function that receives the functional type `(String) -> String` as a `crossinline` argument, then invokes it inside a `object: __` block. That way, you can hide the `object:` in a given function, and externally still be able to call it with a lambda argument. Doesn't seem applicable in this case, though.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is a language level option to do this, but you can abstract the "ugly" code into a helper method so its easier to read where the business logic is actually needed:

**Helper Method**

```
fun Foo(body: (String) -> String) = object : Foo{
  override fun bar(input: String)= body(input)
}
```

**Business Code**

```
fun createFoo():Foo {
  return Foo {input:String -> "Hello $input!"}
}
```

Comment: I updated my question, the interface is defined in kotlin not java.

Comment: @Chriss, this solution works fine with interfaces that are defined in Kotlin. But you can make it a little bit better by adding an `inline` modifier to `Foo` function: `inline fun Foo(crossinline body: (String) -> String) = object : Foo {...}`. It will prevent creating additional `(String) -> String` instance during `Foo` creation. Also, when you use this function, you don't have to specify the type of argument explicitly, the following will work: `Foo { input -> "Hello $input!" }` as well as `Foo { "Hello $it!" }`.

Answer (score 1):

It would be easier in your case to have the interface in Java:

```
fun createFoo() : Foo = Foo { "hello $it" }
```

But as you have a Kotlin interface instead, you are a bit out of luck here. Here is a related issue regarding this: [KT-7770](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-7770)

A workaround to this could be (but that mainly depends on how you use that interface) to have a Kotlin interface as follows in place that is the main entry point for the Java side:

```
interface Foo : (String) -> String
```

On the Kotlin side you will not use it and the Java side should only use it to deliver functions, e.g.

```
// Java class
public class JFooFactory implements FooFactory {
  @Override
  @NotNull
  public Foo createFoo() { // uses the Foo-interface from Kotlin
    return input -> "hello " + input;
  }
}

// Kotlin equivalent:
class KFactory : FooFactory {
  override fun createFoo() : (String) -> String = {
    "hello $it"
  }
}
```

where the corresponding `FooFactory`-interface could look like:

```
interface FooFactory {
  fun createFoo() : (String) -> String
}
```

Usage could look like:

```
listOf(KFooFactory(), JFooFactory())
     .map {
         it.createFoo()
     }
     .forEach { func : (String) -> String -> // i.e. func is of (sub)type (String) -> String
        func("demo") // calling it to deliver "hello demo" twice
     }
```

Alternatively, to have also that `Foo`-feeling for Kotlin you can do it as follows:

```
typealias Foo = (String) -> String
interface JFoo : Foo 
// or if you put the interface in its own package you could also use:   
interface Foo : someother.package.Foo
```

then the Java code stays the same as above, either with `JFoo` or with `Foo` pointing to that other package; the typealias is not visible from Java. The Kotlin side would change to the following:

```
class KFactory : FooFactory {
  override fun createFoo() : Foo = {
    "hello $it"
  }
}
```

The `Factory`-interface could also be replaced:

```
interface FooFactory {
  fun createFoo() : Foo
}
```

Under the hood however everything stays the same. We have/use `(String) -> String` in Kotlin and `Foo`-functional-interface in Java.

Answer (score 0):

To use Kotlin lambda to Java SAM interface conversion anywhere you want, simply specify the name of the interface before the lambda.

```
fun createFoo(): Foo {
   return Foo { input:String -> "Hello $input!" }
}
```

It doesn't even need to be that long.

```
fun createFoo(): Foo {
   return Foo { "Hello $it!" }
}
```

As long as the interface has a single method and is declared in Java, that's all you need to do.

Comment: I updated my question, the interface is defined in kotlin not java.