# Unable to use lambda arrow expression for Livedata observe method in Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin

I am new to kotlin and I am a little confused while using lambda expression in LiveData observe method.

The signature for observe method is as follows

```
observe(LifecycleOwner owner, Observer<? super T> observer)
```

where Observer is an interface with a single method

```
void onChanged (T t)
```

However,calling the above observe method in kotlin as follows gives type mismatch error :

```
 val myViewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(AnimeListViewModel::class.java)

 myViewModel.animes.observe(this, { anime -> println(anime) })
```

Isn't this the same as calling the setOnClickListener on a view. The following piece of code works perfectly without any compilation error:

```
val myView = View(this)

myView.setOnClickListener { view -> println(view) }
```

I have already read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47604918/kotlin-syntax-for-livedata-observer) answer which shows how to call the method using lambda expression (using SAM conversion). However, I am still not sure why a simple arrow expression would fail.

Answer (score 1):

LiveData doesn't have a lambda expression, you should pass the observer interface as an object

```
myViewModel.animes.observe(this, Observer { anime -> println(anime) })
```

Or by creating an extension function like this

```
fun <T : Any> LiveData<T>.observe(lifecycleOwner: LifecycleOwner, block: (T) -> Unit) = observe(lifecycleOwner, Observer(block))
```

And calling it like this

```
myViewModel.animes.observe(this) { anime -> println(anime) }
```

Or like this

```
fun main() {
   myViewModel.animes.observe(this, ::handleLiveData)
}

fun handleLiveData(anime: Anime) {
   println(anime)
}
```

Comment: In latest Kotlin plugin 1.3.40-release-Studio3.4-1 there is a defect that gives precedence of the normal `observe()` method over the extension thus it automatically thinks it is unused and removes the import (if auto-import is enabled on your AS) but the compiler complains. I guess it's related to the new type inference engine they introduced recently.

Answer (score 0):

There are some problems on kotlin to resolve generics, so that's the reason. Kotlin has been working on this, and you will find the whole explanation
[here](https://youtu.be/MyljSWm0Y_k?t=1166).